# Shimano Claris st-2400 3x8 or 2x8?

Tags: shimano, shifter

I wanted to purchase Shimano claris st-2400 and I was confused since some places say its a 2x8 and some other say its 3x8 . For example [https://www.amazon.com/Shimano-ST-2400-Claris-Shift-3x8-Speed/dp/B00CABMRN0/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1497286590&sr=8-1&keywords=shimano+claris+3x8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CABMRN0) this amazon listing says ST-2400 is 3x8 . Could someone please clarify?

Thanking You
Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two versions of the 2400 series, 2x8 and 3x8. The 3x8 version is usually labelled as 2403, but if the amazon description says that it is 3x8, then that specific product is probably the 3x8 version. Based on the reviews and description, this appears to be the 3x8 version.